# Using a select statement for columns with spaces in it

Tags: mysql, sql, request

I have 2 tables:

First Table Suivi
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Second Table OGRAF
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I would like to update the RAFHJ value on the table Suivi, following a change of the Status or the Service. The OGRAF table represent the RAFHJ for each combination.

For example: the Table Suivi I have the 977th project that is on the 4th Status for a MFW so according to the OGRAF Table, RAFHJ should be 5, and it is so it's all good. Now if the Status change to 5 - Install/Config, RAFHJ should become 4, still according to the OGRAF table.

For the moment I'm just trying to get the value that I need.
The thing is that the column names have space in it so I can't do this kind of request:

```
Select (Select Status from Suivi where idProject=1) 
from OGRAF, Suivi 
WHERE Suivi.Service=OGRAF.Service and Suivi.idProject=1;
```

It works if I do this:

```
Select `8 - Tests` 
from OGRAF, Suivi 
WHERE Suivi.Service=OGRAF.Service and Suivi.idProject=1;
```

It's been hours that I'm trying to solve this and I started SQL recently so if anyone can help me with that I would be thankful.

Comment: As I understand your question, you want to select the column from OGRAF that has the same name as the value in Suivi.Status?

Comment: I want to select the value of the cell of OGRAF which as Suivi.Service=OGRAF.Service and also Suivi.Status=OGRAF.(the name of the column)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Select [8 - Tests] 
from OGRAF, Suivi 
WHERE Suivi.Service=OGRAF.Service and Suivi.idProject=1;
```

Give it a go

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work". Does it crash? Does it show a different result?

Comment: I got an error Message: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[8 - Tests]
from OGRAF, Suivi
WHERE Suivi.Service=OGRAF.Service and Suivi.idPr' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the following answer might help.

You might want to tag your question as MySQL and write a better text (your request is not clear - you don't specify what value is put into table Suivi column RAFHJ from table OGRAF).

MySql (not checked) example:

```
update Suivi su
  join OGRAF og on su.Service = og.Service
set
  su.RAFHJ = 2
where su.idProject = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my post and I hope it's better to understand now.

Answer (score 0):

MySql has a syntax which allows space inside name of columns. You have to enclosed the name with backtick `

If you have the same name of column in multiple table in the join list, you can use the table name to prefix the column in the select list to remove ambiguity.

[See fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31fdf7/4)